# Serializing a "complex" class c#

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having a lot of problems serializing a quite complex class into a file stored in the LocalFolder of the phone. I've tried Json seriliazitaion with newtonSoft package and with xmlserializer also.

This the class I'm trying to store and load from file:

```
public class Gear
{
    public int LastUsedGroup { get; set; }
    public List<GearGroupName> GearTree { get; set; }
}

public class GearItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool ToTake { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public bool DoneEnabled { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Background { get; set; }
    public double Opacity { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}


public class GearGroupName
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<GearItem> GearGroup = new List<GearItem>();
}
```

I've have some hardcoded info into the class. But when trying to serialize into the file using this (see below) I get errors (NullReference for XmlSerialization and StackOverFlow error for Json).

namespace ReadWriteUniversal
{

```
class XmlIO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads XML content from a file ("filename") and returns an object  from the XML
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<T> ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync<T>(string filename)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        T objectFromXml = default(T);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        objectFromXml = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Dispose();
        return objectFromXml;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Stores an object in XML format in file called 'filename'
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectToSave"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task SaveObjectToXml<T>(T objectToSave, string filename)
    {             
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        Type t = typeof(T);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
        using (stream)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
        }
    }

}

class JsonIO
{
    public static async Task<T> ReadObjectFromJsonFileAsync<T>(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            // this reads XML content from a file ("filename") and returns an object  from the XML
            //T objectFromXml = default(T);
            //var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            //Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting Json reading");
            string strJson = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            Debug.WriteLine("Read" + strJson);

            return (T)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);

            //objectFromXml = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            //stream.Dispose();
            //return objectFromXml;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

    }

    public static async Task SaveObjectToJson<T>(T objectToSave, string filename)
    {
        // stores an object in XML format in file called 'filename'
        //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        //Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        string strJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSave);

        Debug.WriteLine("Write- " + strJson);

        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, strJson);
        //using (stream)
        //{
        //    serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
        //}
    }
}
```

}

Any idea why it happens?

If it helps, here is the hardcoded part for testing purposes.

```
    private void staticData()
    {
        // TODO: 
        // LinkGroupName-ak sartu. Pivot-etan agertuko direnak

        // MENDIA ELURRAREKIN
        GearGroupName ggn = new GearGroupName();
        ggn.GroupName = "Mendiko materiala elurrarekin";

        // Group bakoitzari elementuak gehitu
        GearItem gear;

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Toaila";
        gear.Index = 0;
        gear.DoneEnabled = gear.ToTake;
        if (gear.ToTake)
            gear.Opacity = 1.0;
        else
            gear.Opacity = 0.5;

        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Kamara estalkia";
        gear.Index = 1;
        gear.ToTake = true;
        gear.DoneEnabled = gear.ToTake;
        if (gear.ToTake)
            gear.Opacity = 1.0;
        else
            gear.Opacity = 0.5;

        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Eskularruak";
        gear.Index = 2;
        gear.ToTake = true;
        gear.DoneEnabled = gear.ToTake;
        if (gear.ToTake)
            gear.Opacity = 1.0;
        else
            gear.Opacity = 0.5;

        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);


        myGear.GearTree.Add(ggn);

        // KOSTA
        ggn = new GearGroupName();
        ggn.GroupName = "Kosta";

        // Group bakoitzari elementuak gehitu
        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Katiuskak";
        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Uretako oinetakoak";
        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Badeadorea";
        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        myGear.GearTree.Add(ggn);

        // BIDAIATZEKO
        ggn = new GearGroupName();
        ggn.GroupName = "Bidai materiala";

        gear = new GearItem();
        gear.Description = "Tripodea";
        ggn.GearGroup.Add(gear);

        myGear.GearTree.Add(ggn);

    }
```

Comment: There's nothing "complex" about your class, but you're trying to serialize a `SolidColorBrush`, which was *not* designed for JSON serialization. Putting aside the fact that you seem to be mixing UI and logic concepts, just put a `[JsonIgnore]` on this property, and serialize a *different* `string BackgroundHex` property for instance, which will proxy to the `Background` property through a color hex code.

Comment: It just worked! Thanks a lot @LucasTrzesniewski !

I didn't know that not standard types caused this kind of problems at serializations...

Now, to test Loading part of the json file!